# Determine the value of $\sum_{k=0}^n i^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, geometric-series

[this is the problem:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CAgM.png)

> Determine the value of the sum $\sum_{k=0}^n i^k$ for $n \in \Bbb N$.

I started to sum term by term but don't get its value

Comment: This is a geometric sum.

Comment: yeah, sorry i'm learning complex numbers and saw the sum i thought it was part of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$S = i^0 + i^1 + i^2 + ... + i^{n-1} + i^n$

$Si = i^1 + i^2 + i^3 + ... + i^n + i^{n+1}$

$Si - S = i^{n+1} - i^0$

$S(i-1) = i^{n+1} - i^0$

$S = \dfrac{i^{n+1} - 1}{i-1}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  I want to know what $1 + i + i^2 + i^3 + ..... + i^n$ is.

So here is a question.  What is $(1-i)(1 + i + i^2 + i^3 + ..... + i^n)$?

so if $(1-i)(1 + i + i^2 + i^3 + ..... + i^n)= M$ and if we assume $i \ne 1$ then that would mean $1 + i + i^2 + i^3 + ..... + i^n = \frac M{1-i}$.

This is a very common result that you will see a *lot* in your career.  It's always fun to try to see if you can figure it out entirely on your own, but most of us had someone else show it to us and we all went "Oh, yeah!  That's neat!"